# Add Xamarin.Forms template missing from project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, c#-3.0, visual-studio-2019

I am having the following issue in VS 2019. I have a project that was working correctly and able to add Xamarin.Forms templates through the Add New Item dialogue. A Windows update (update to .net framework and Windows itself) and VS 2019 update later and now it is not working in my current project. I have done the following:

1. Reinstalled Xamarin forms in VS 2019
2. Removed Xamarin forms from VS 2017 that I have installed
3. Installed older versions of the .net framework
4. Updated Xamarin.Forms under the Nuget Package manager to the latest version in the current project.

I have set up a test project named App2 that is allowing the creation of Xamarin.Forms pages, on the same computer.

Other info:

- Windows Version: Win 10 Pro 1909, build 18363.752
- VS 2019 Version: 16.5.2
- .Net Framework Version: 4.8.03752
- Xamarin Version: 16.5.000.528
- The main project is compiling and running correctly.

Is there any guidance that you can give me?

Screenshots:

[The main project Add New Item Dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1DKb.png)

[The App2 project Add New Item Dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XU7r.png)

Comment: As an update when attempting to work with the main project in Jet Brains Rider the Xamarin Form option does not appear either.

Comment: looks like it must be too old project, may be migrate it to newer .netstandard 2 should help

Comment: That sounds like an idea do you know of any guides to accomplish this?

Comment: I would just manually edit csproj file by comparing with latest project. You can also create fresh project and solution add your files one by one too.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try that and get back to you.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Does that mean I need to re create whole project in newer Visual studio?

Comment: Unfortnuately yes, the project needs to be updated to the latest format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is exactly what Morse suggested, I had to move the project into a new.

@Morse, thank you for the answers.